Any quantum Monte-Carlo algorithm for calculating the lowest eigenenergy in each symmetry sector?
Suppose we have a hamiltonian which has the parity symmetry (e.g., the Heisenberg model with the open boundary condition). Is there any quantum Monte-Carlo algorithm which can be used to calculate the ground state energy in the odd-parity sector?
Often, the global ground state is in the even-parity sector, and in my impression, there are many algorithms for calculating the global ground state energy. However, now I want the lowest eigenenergy in the odd-parity sector.
An idea is to use an odd-parity variational wave function and do variational monte carlo calculation. However, in my impression, the accuracy is often not high.
